# asp.net Membership : Extending Role membership?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, roles

I am been taking a look at asp.net membership and it seems to provide everything that i need but i need some kind of custom Role functionality.

Currently i can add user to a role, great.

But i also need to be able to add Permissions to Roles..

i.e.

Role: Editor
Permissions: Can View Editor Menu, Can Write to Editors Table, Can Delete Entries in Editors Table.

Currently it doesn't support this, The idea behind this is to create a admin option in my program to create a role and then assign permissions to a role to say "allow the user to view a certain part of the application", "allow the user to open a menu item"

Any ideas how i would implement soemthing like this?

I presume a custom ROLE provider but i was wondering if some kind of framework extension existed already without rolling my own?

Or anybody knows a good tutorial of how to tackle this issue?

I am quite happy with what asp.net SQL provider has created in terms of tables etc... but i think i need to extend this by adding another table called RolesPermissions

and then I presume :-)  adding some kind of enumeration into the table for each valid permission??

THanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically permit or not permit to the user to see some pages, or do some actions using for example the function **IsInRole**, and check if you let or not a user to do some actions.

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("rolename")
```

You can make a class/or table with your permissions, and depend from the role that a user belong, to open, close, permit etc a lot of thinks on the same page. I have programming an idea like that on my programs, is very simple.

Here is an idea...

```
public enum csPermissions
{
    pActionDelete = 1,   
    pActionEdit = 2 , 
    ...more actions...
}

private int[] AdminPermission = { 
    (int)csPermissions.pActionEdit, 
    (int)csPermissions.pActionDelete, 
    ....
};

private int[] BackOfficePermission = { 
    (int)csPermissions.pActionEdit, 
    ....
}; 

public static bool IsThisAllowed(csPermissions AskPermitForThisAction)
{
    ... questions here for all users roles...
    ... here is only an example .....
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administator")))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AdminPermission.Length; i++)
            if (AdminPermission[i] == (int)AskPermitForThisAction)
                return true;
    } 

    ...  
    return false;
 }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the framework to restrict access to entire pages or directories based upon roles. This can be configured in the web.config's authorization element.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx

Additionally, if you're using a SiteMap for your menu, and have configured authorization, you can use security trimming to restrict the menu. http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+security+trimming